# Rails Active Storage + AWS Rekognition: How to get IO file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-rekognition

I'm trying to integrate AWS Rekognition into my Rails app. After the user uploads his avatar via Active Storage, Rekognition should show some info about it.

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update(user_params)
      if @user.images.attached?
        Aws.config.update({
            region: 'us-west-2',
            credentials: Aws::Credentials.new('ACCESS_KEY', 'SECRET_KEY')
          })
          rekognition = Aws::Rekognition::Client.new(region: Aws.config[:region], credentials: Aws.config[:credentials])
          img = @user.images.first. # original was: File.read(ARGV.first)

          #detect faces  
          resp = rekognition.detect_faces({
            image: { bytes: img },
            attributes: ["ALL"], # What attributes to return
          })
          resp.face_details[0].emotions.each do |emo|
            puts emo.type + " " + emo.confidence.to_i.to_s #=> Strings "HAPPY", "SAD", "ANGRY"
          end
      end
   end
end
```

However, I get the error

`expected params[:image][:bytes] to be a String or IO object, got value #<ActiveStorage::Attachment id: 4, name: "images", record_type: "User", record_id: 47, blob_id: 9, created_at: ""> (class: ActiveStorage::Attachment) instead.`

How can I get the image file property into AWS Rekognition?

Answer (score 1):

There is two way to pass image to `Aws::Rekognition`.

1. AWS S3 image url and name

> ```
> resp = rekognition.detect_faces(
>         {image:
>           {s3_object:
>             {bucket: `bucket name`,
>               name: `pull path of file`,
>             },
>           }, attributes: ['ALL'],
>         }
>       )
> ```

2. Via Image object

> ```
> rekognition.detect_faces({
>          image: { bytes: File.read(`path of file`) }
>        })
> ```

in your case you are passing `ActiveStorage` object that can't parse by AWS. that's why it throw error.